# Facebook app permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I have an iOS app which posts to Facebook on behalf of the user logged in through the iOS Facebook setting.

Two problems -

1. the posts are marked private, the users friends don't see them.
2. The iOS app want to be able to harvest Like and Comment info but I get back a 400 from FB.

Here's the wrinkle, my Facebook account works perfectly (posts are visible to friends and I can get the Like and Comment info), but a test user account will post only as private and the iOS app gets a 400 when trying to get post info.

The attached screen shots show the different permissions (top for tester, bottom for me) but I can figure out what to ask Facebook for at login to get the same permissions for both users. Currently I'm asking for `publish_actions` and `user_status`.

Any help would be much appreciated![image: permissions screenshot]

Comment: 1. Is your app in dev mode? 2. If its live, are your permissions approved by facebook if you are using v2.0? 3. Which test user account are you talking of?

Comment: App is live. Using v2.0. I've added "read_stream" to my 2nd login and can now see the test users post! Next problem - when calling the graph to get Like and Comment info I get back a reference to all the posts my FB app has done not the individual post I ask for with the post_id. ie. h t tps://graph.facebook.com/"+postID+"?access_token=token.

Comment: This returns; {"id":"100008286791946_1440572172895662","from":{"id":"100008286791946","name":"Ppip Tester"},"story":"Ppip Tester added 4 new photos to the album Picture Planner Connect Photos.","picture":"https:\/\/scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-xpf1\/t1.0-9\/p130x130\/10501959_1441104376175775_6203575761140635283_n.jpg","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/photo.php?fbid=1441104376175775&set=a.1440548079564738.1073741825.100008286791946&type=1&relevant_count=4","name":"Picture Planner Connect Photos","icon":

Comment: "https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yz\/r\/StEh3RhPvjk.gif","actions":[{"name":"Comment","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/100008286791946\/posts\/1440572172895662"},{"name":"Like","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/100008286791946\/posts\/1440572172895662"}],"privacy":{"description":"Your friends","value":"ALL_FRIENDS","friends":"","networks":"","allow":"","deny":""},"type":"photo","status_type":"added_photos","object_id":"1441104376175775","application":{"name":"Picture Planner Connect","namespace":

Comment: "pictureplanner","id":"191830440843737"},"created_time":"2014-07-07T20:34:28+0000","updated_time":"2014-07-07T20:34:28+0000"}

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are asking for public_profile also you need to make sure you split your permission access into two pieces, as per FB, 1) read 2) write

Just follow the login process on the Facebook Dev page, this will allow you to outline your permissions the right way. Also make sure your test user is added into the groups on your Facebook Dev portal.

Also can you provide any code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the post_id element was not what I wanted but rather the id. After that I could use json to get the comments and likes. So the call was almost correct.

And adding stream_read to the permissions got the post to be visible to friends...

Thanks for all the help!